# Как найти высоту над уровнем моря?

Tags: математика, google-maps-api, google-maps, геолокация

Имеется две геоточки `A` ( `x1` (latitude), `y1` (longitude), `z1` ( elevation) ) и `B` ( `x2`, `y2`, `z2` ), также знаем расстояние ( `d` ) между этими двумя точками.

Как найти `z2` высоту над уровнем моря, не используя интернет ?

Comment: По идее вы можете вычислит высоту построим линию между А и B нетак ли? Но тут зарылась мелкая собачёнка, в 3D пространстве линия не котируется. Зона 3D спроэцированая на плоскость в качестве линии будет слишком малой, вам понадобится треугольник (три точки), а лучше "квадрат", т.е. 4-ре точки. По 3-4 точкам думаю можно прописать формулу высоты. Но это уже идёт раздел математики. Если вас всётаки интерисует формула линии - сейчас напишем.

Comment: "Зона 3D спроэцированая на плоскость в качестве линии будет слишком малой" - вроде и слова все знакомые...

Comment: Для вашего случая ф-ла простая. z(x) =   ((|x - x0| / |x1 - x0|) * |z0 - z1|) + min (z0,z1) при условии что мы находимся на линии между А и B. Так как это "двухмерка" то координата Y нас не интерисует - она "сокращается". Такое же выражение можна написать для z(y)

Comment: Хотя вы можете попробовать взять и записать z = (z(x) + z(y)) / 2, возможно для вас этого результата будет и достаточно. Но точность не гарантируется.

Comment: @nick_n_a - обратите, пожалуйста, внимание на слова "широта" и "долгота" (latitude и longitude) в вопросе. "Собака рылась" именно здесь. Перед использованием теоремы Пифагора, эти географические координаты надо перевести в декартовы.

Comment: @SaluteAmigo - Вы широту и долготу не перепутали? Обычно x - это долгота, а y - широта.

Comment: @Igor для наших широт можно не переводить, тем более что врядли усреднения будут касатся 100км и больше. По хорошему перевести бы. В районе полюсов погрешность будет большая. Тут пропорция, и надо понимать что через две точки на 3D плоскости мы можем построить лишь линию. В моём случае она будет чуть "скруглена" по линии мередиана. Для более точных расчётов нужна сложнее формула.

Comment: @nick_n_a Какие "усреднения"? Мера географических координат - угол, а не длина.

Comment: @Igor Когда строится пропорция то выходит   (угол - угол0 / dугол) - безразмерная величина (еденичная, от 0 до 1). Поэтому это не важно. (При использовании именно такого подхода). Напишите свою формулу:)

Comment: @nick_n_a *Так как это "двухмерка" то координата Y нас не интерисует - она "сокращается".* - лихо!

Comment: @nick_n_a *Такое же выражение можна написать для z(y)*  - и какой же результат потом использовать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как найти высоту над уровнем моря без интернета?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645064/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4-%d1%83%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: @SaluteAmigo вам нужно значение высот между точками А B, или вам таки нужно "по-пифагору" посчитать z2 = f(ax,ay,bx,by,distance) ?

Comment: Не ответили на вопрос -- зададим ещё один, точно такой же? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645064/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

Есть уравнение линии.
Его общий вид такой  (x-x0)/(y-y0) = (x1-x0)/(y1-y0)

Для случая когда каждые 1-5 км точек высоты извесны, вы можете перейти к простому случаю, просто расчитать высоту между точками А и В просто параметрическими уравнениями пропорции. Для двухмерная случая третья координата не обязательна. Вашу линию высоты для точек A(x0,y0) B(x1,y1) можно записать ввиде:

z(x) = ((x-x0)/(x1-x0))*(z1-z0) + z0   при   x между x0 и x1

z(y) = ((y-y0)/(y1-y0))*(z1-z0) + z0   при   y между y0 и y1

На линии z(x) будет всегда равно z(y), а вот вне линии - мы не знаем, но можно записать как усреднение (z(x)+z(y))/2

Допустим высота А = 10, высота B = 50 - тогда эти два графика датут такую картину:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где синим z(x) зеленым z(y), жёлтое наша линия. Цифрами подписаны расчётные высоты формул приведеных выше.

Единственный "минус", это нужно разобраться со знаками. Для `x0<x1` `y0<y1` `z0<z1` эти формулы работают. Для остальных случаев нужно проверять. Случай когда `z1<z0` приводит к тому что скобка 3 меняет знак, и из большей величины высоты вычитается "приведеная"  высота. Осталось рассмотреть 3 случая: а) `x0>x1 y0<y1` б) `x0<x1 y0>y1` в) `x0<x1 y0<y1` и возможно поменять местами 0 и 1 или поправить знаки.

По поводу угол или расстояние - это не имеет значение, поскольку в выражении `(x - x0)/ (x1 - x0)` размерность сокращается, это выражение всегда будет в диапазоне от [0... +/- 1] и умноженое на дельта-высоту + высота0 оно всегда даст значение от высота0 до высота1

Линии X я провёл специально криво, что б показать что "погрешность на изгиб линии широты" незначительная. Я думаю что она проявится если расстояние между A B более 10-30 км. 100км точно не рекомендую. Если результат изображённый на графике вас устраивает - можете использовать эти формулы.

Comment: Красивая картинка :). Особенно мне понравились параллельные и прямые меридианы на протяжении сорока градусов, и загибающиеся как клюшки параллели. Вы, конечно, знаете, что один градус это примерно сто километров? А сорок градусов - это почти четверть протяженности меридиана от полюса до полюса.

Comment: Да, я знаю, мне до дома 4 градуса, т.е. 500км))) Мне показалось что задача автора расставить высоты если извесны точки A B между которыми 1-2 км. В таком случае можно так записать.Кто-то не оценил такое решение. Спасибо вы оценили мои труды.

Answer (score 0):

Попробую написать в ответ:

[Elevation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevation) - Это и есть высота над уровнем моря. Вам достаточно использовать `z2`

Comment: Я думаю в ответе лучше указать формулу. Статья достаточно большая.

Comment: формула: высота = z2